# "No such core" exception using EmbeddedSolrServer

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I'm trying to connect to Solr index using Solrj and in paticular `EmbeddedSolrServer`. My `solr.xml` look like this:

```
<solr>  
  <cores adminPath="/admin/cores" defaultCoreName="db">
        <core default="true" instanceDir="../db/" name="db"/>
  </cores>
</solr>
```

When executing a query command to the server

```
CoreContainer coreContainer = new CoreContainer("C:\\development\\solr-4.4.0\\example tasks\\solr");
EmbeddedSolrServer server = new EmbeddedSolrServer(coreContainer, "db");

Collection<SolrCore> cores = coreContainer.getCores();
System.out.println(cores);


SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
query.setQuery("*:*");
query.addFacetField("taskType", "taskName");
QueryResponse rsp = server.query(query);
```

I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: No such core: db
```

The `db` core is there and when I start Solr using Jetty and the same `solr.xml` file, everything works perfect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT after comments:**

In version 4.4.0 you need to use `load()` function to load the cores.

```
CoreContainer coreContainer = new CoreContainer("C:\\development\\solr-4.4.0\\example tasks\\solr");
container.load();
```

If you haven't already seen the [solr wiki for EmbeddedSolrSever](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj#EmbeddedSolrServer), please have a look.

I hope it solves your problem.

Comment: if you take time and check 4.4.0 version, I will see that `CoreContainer.Initializer` is not anymore there. All other code is taken from wiki.

Comment: I see sorry, I overlooked your version, you need to use container.load() to load the cores. Please check my edited answer.

Comment: hi, not yet, I'm enjoying the weekend :) but tomorrow I will try it out and write back to you.

Comment: thanks it helped. I wonder why the official documentation was not updated.

Comment: Yeah, they should have updated. I'm not sure too why they haven't.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Solr 4.4 there is an alternate core definition method using the discovery of core directories and core.properties files. This method is mandatory starting with Solr 5.0.

Note: Your core definitions in solr.xml will need to be migrated to the new method.
For more information see [Solr.xml 4.4 and beyond](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solr.xml%204.4%20and%20beyond)

Answer (score 0):

This happens mostly when [`EmbeddedSolrServer`](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/8_7_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/embedded/EmbeddedSolrServer.html) is unable to find the core. Usually because the `core.properties` file is missing (have a look at [Solr configuration files](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_7/solr-configuration-files.html)).

I wrote a Java example that helps to write your own test configuration, load data and run junit tests.

https://github.com/freedev/EmbeddedSolrServer-junit-example